# No consigo que se manden los archivos de uno en uno

Tags: javascript

Tengo que hacer un lavado de cara al código que ya tenía hecho para que funcione correctamente con varios archivos.

Cuando meto varios archivos a un `input file`, los recojo con el `JS` para meterlos en un `array` llamado `pool` mediante un bucle `for`, y después PRETENDO mandar cada objeto a otra función uno por uno, esperando a que se ejecute dicha función de principio a fin para mandar el siguiente.

Esto funciona mal, ya que NUNCA los manda todos, en el código comentado explico lo que hace cada cosa:

```
function selectFile(){
    let file = _("file1");

    if('files' in file){
      let pool = [], x;

      for(let i=0;i < file.files.length;i++){//iteramos el array de ficheros
          x = file.files[i];//asignamos en cada iteracion al fichero en x
          pool.push(x);//push en pool de x
          console.log(pool);//accion de bucle completa previa a ejecucion de codigo

          //despliegue del temp
          txt = createElement();
          document.body.append(txt);
          //logs
          if ('name' in x) {txt.getElementsByClassName('txt_file_name')[0].innerHTML = '<strong>Name:</strong> '+x.name;};
          if ('size' in x) {txt.getElementsByClassName('txt_file_size')[0].innerHTML = '<strong>Size:</strong> '+x.size;};
      }

      //salta por alto esta variable
      let snd_upload = () => {
        console.log('Se ejecuta snd_upload');
        if(pool.length){  
          console.log(pool.length);    
          let p1 = pool.shift();//cogemos el primer objeto de pool
          console.log('Mandando archivo "'+p1.name+'" para descomprimir');
          uploadComplete(p1, function(){snd_upload();console.log('se manda snd_upload')});//mandamos el objeto a upload complete
          //no hay reiteracion...por que
        }
      };
      
      //y lo manda desde aquí de forma recursiva
      //tantos objetos hay en pool
      snd_upload();
    }
}
```

SIN EMBARGO, en la función uploadComplete, en la que desfragmento el archivo en chunks y lo mando a otra función, trato de seguir la misma lógica, y me sale bien, mas o menos, ya que también tiene fallos, pero al menos se consigue reiterar:

```
function uploadComplete(x) {
  console.log(x);

  let pol =[];
  let start = 0;
  let end = BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
  let part = 0;
  let charged = 0;
  //se hace solo una vez
  //se sube el archivo una vez

  while( start < x.size ) {
    //se divide el archivo mientras start sea menor al size total
    //se ejecuta cuantas veces se divida el archivo
    start = end;
    end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
    part++;
    pol.push({part:part,start:start,end:end});

    console.log(pol);//iteramos los que van a ser los fragmentos del archivo mandado
  }

  console.log('esto va despues del while');
  let fnupload = ()=>{
    console.log('y despues esto');
    if(pol.length){
      let p1 = pol.shift();
      let chunk = x.slice(p1.start, p1.end);
      uploadFile(chunk, p1.part, x, function(){fnupload();console.log('se manda')});//esto se ejecuta a partir de la SEGUNDA vez que lo mando
      //por que
      console.log('complete', p1.part);
    }
  }; 
  
  console.log('ejecuta esto primero');
  fnupload();
}
```

Dicha función llama a otra, uploadFile:

```
function uploadFile(chunkFile, part, x, uploadLoaded){
  //se ejecuta tantas veces esté dividido el archivo
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let fd = new FormData();
  let chunks = Math.max(Math.ceil(x.size / BYTES_PER_CHUNK), 1);
  let bar = txt.getElementsByClassName('progressBar')[0];

  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress",(event)=>{uploadProgress(event, bar, x)}, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("loadend", uploadLoaded, false);

  fd.append("file1", chunkFile);
  fd.append("num", part);
  fd.append("chunks", chunks);
  fd.append("namae", x.name);

  xhr.open("POST", "upload.php", true);
  xhr.send(fd);
}

function uploadProgress(event, bar, x){

  _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded " + event.loaded + " bytes of " + event.total;
  let percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
  bar.value = Math.round(percent);
  _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent) + "% uploaded... please wait";
}

function uploadFailed(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = "Upload failed";
}
  
function uploadCanceled(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = "Upload canceled";
}
```

Y no, no tengo uploadLoaded. No entiendo muy bien cómo podría solucionar esto.

---

**[EDIT]**

Snippets con el html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="form_aaron.js"></script>

<body>

  <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
    <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" onchange="selectFile()" multiple size="50"><br>
    <h3 id="status"></h3>
    <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
    <input type="submit" id="btn-progressbar" value="Upload" style="visibility:hidden">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sería bueno poner snippets con el HTML.

Comment: ahora mismo lo edito

Comment: Me sale que no existe `_`

Comment: Ah, cierto, es que es una función a parte, perdona, es un getElementById con return del id, ahora lo cambio. Igualmente ya solucioné un problema, me queda el otro

Comment: Respecto a _"Y no, no tengo uploadLoaded."_, es el último parámetro de la función `uploadFile()` y le estás enviando una función anónima en `uploadFile(chunk, p1.part, x, function(){ fnupload(); console.log('se manda')});`. Realmente es esa función anónima la que recorre los elementos de `pol` cada que termina una subida. Ahora, la pregunta es ¿porqué subir archivos de uno en uno? Es entendible para manejar las partes (chunks) de un archivo, pero no para el proceso general, porque se hará más lento.

Comment: @Triby, me lo mandaron así por si el servidor no aceptaba muchos envíos a la vez. Es más, si no los mandaba de uno en uno, tendría que hacer promesas o algo por el estilo para que no se solaparan unos con otros XD

Answer (score 0):

Vale, ya corregí el código (trasteando y sin querer...), así es como quedaría de forma final el código en JS, en HTML y en PHP (lo adjunto todo por si a alguien le llega a interesar):

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="form_aaron.js"></script>

<body>

  <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
    <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" onchange="selectFile()" multiple size="50"><br>
    <h3 id="status"></h3>
    <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
    <input type="submit" id="btn-progressbar" value="Upload" style="visibility:hidden">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var txt, BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 2097152;

function selectFile(){
    let file = _("file1");

    if('files' in file){
      let pool = [], x;

      for(let i=0;i < file.files.length;i++){//iteramos el array de ficheros
          x = file.files[i];//asignamos en cada iteracion al fichero en x
          pool.push(x);//push en pool de x
          console.log(pool);//accion de bucle completa previa a ejecucion de codigo

          //despliegue del temp
          txt = createElement();
          document.body.append(txt);
          //logs
          if ('name' in x) {txt.getElementsByClassName('txt_file_name')[0].innerHTML = '<strong>Name:</strong> '+x.name;};
          if ('size' in x) {txt.getElementsByClassName('txt_file_size')[0].innerHTML = '<strong>Size:</strong> '+x.size;};
      }

      //salta por alto esta variable
      let snd_upload = () => {
        console.log('Se ejecuta snd_upload');
        if(pool.length){  
          console.log(pool.length);    
          let p1 = pool.shift();//cogemos el primer objeto de pool
          console.log('Mandando archivo "'+p1.name+'" para descomprimir');
          uploadComplete(p1, function(){snd_upload();console.log('se manda snd_upload')});//mandamos el objeto a upload complete
          //no hay reiteracion...por que
        }
      };
      
      //y lo manda desde aquí de forma recursiva
      //tantos objetos hay en pool
      snd_upload();
    }
}

function uploadComplete(x, snd_upload) {
  console.log(x);

  let pol =[];
  let start = 0;
  let end = BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
  let part = 0;
  let charged = 0;
  //se hace solo una vez
  //se sube el archivo una vez

  while( start < x.size ) {
    //se divide el archivo mientras start sea menor al size total
    //se ejecuta cuantas veces se divida el archivo
    pol.push({part:part,start:start,end:end});
    start = end;
    end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
    part++;
    console.log(pol);//iteramos los que van a ser los fragmentos del archivo mandado
  }

  console.log('esto va despues del while');
  let fnupload = ()=>{
    console.log('y despues esto');
    if(pol.length){
      let p1 = pol.shift();
      let chunk = x.slice(p1.start, p1.end);
      console.log(chunk);
      uploadFile(chunk, p1.part, x, function(){fnupload();console.log('se manda')});//esto se ejecuta a partir de la SEGUNDA vez que lo mando
      //por que
      console.log('complete', p1.part);

      if(pol.length == 0){
        snd_upload();
      }
    }
  }; 
  
  console.log('ejecuta esto primero');
  fnupload();
}

function uploadFile(chunkFile, part, x, uploadLoaded){//se manda uploadLoaded
  //se ejecuta tantas veces esté dividido el archivo
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let fd = new FormData();
  let chunks = Math.max(Math.ceil(x.size / BYTES_PER_CHUNK), 1);
  let bar = txt.getElementsByClassName('progressBar')[0];

  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress",(event)=>{uploadProgress(event, bar, x)}, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("loadend", uploadLoaded, false);//y aqui tambien
  //pero no hay ninguna funcion llamada asi, no lo entiendo

  fd.append("file1", chunkFile);
  fd.append("num", part);
  fd.append("chunks", chunks);
  fd.append("namae", x.name);

  xhr.open("POST", "upload.php", true);
  xhr.send(fd);
}

function uploadProgress(event, bar, x){

  _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded " + event.loaded + " bytes of " + event.total;
  let percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
  bar.value = Math.round(percent);
  _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent) + "% uploaded... please wait";
}

function uploadFailed(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = "Upload failed";
}
  
function uploadCanceled(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = "Upload canceled";
}

function createElement(){
  let dv = document.createElement('div');
      dv.setAttribute('class', 'demo');
  let p1 = document.createElement('p');
      p1.setAttribute('class', 'txt_file_name');
  let p2 = document.createElement('p');
      p2.setAttribute('class', 'txt_file_size');
  let pr = document.createElement('progress');
      pr.setAttribute('class', 'progressBar');
      pr.setAttribute('value', '0');
      pr.setAttribute('max', '100');

      dv.append(p1);
      dv.append(p2);
      dv.append(pr);

  return dv;
}

function _(el) {
  return document.getElementById(el);
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$target_path = 'archivos_aaron_pruebas/';
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
$size = $_FILES['file1']['size'];
$name = $_FILES['file1']['name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file1']['type'];
$num = $_POST['num'];
$num_chunks = $_POST['chunks'];
$namae = $_POST['namae'];



move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target_path.$num.$name);

// count ammount of uploaded chunks
$chunksUploaded = 0;
for($i = 0; $i <= $num_chunks; $i++){
    if(file_exists($target_path.$i.$name)){
        ++$chunksUploaded;
    }
}

//avengers...
if($chunksUploaded == $num_chunks){
  
    //reassemble
    for($i = 0;$i <= $num_chunks; $i++){
        $file = fopen($target_path.$i.$name, 'rb');
        $buff = fread($file, 2097152);
        fclose($file);

        $final = fopen($target_path.$namae, 'ab');
        $write = fwrite($final, $buff);
        fclose($final);

        unlink($target_path.$i.$name);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Como se menciona en el comentario, el primer error es el `_`, es el `getElementById("file1")`... Se puede reemplazar por `querySelector` agregando un `#` al principio.

```
document.querySelector("file1")
```

Lo siguiente no es común verlo en JavaScript:

```js
console.log('files' in {"files": []})
```

Yo recomendaría usar la función `Object.keys`, o directamente comprobar que no sea `null`, de esta manera `files.file == null`... También es posible comprobar si existe, solamente escribiendo el nombre de la variable dentro del `if`, así... `if(file.files){`:

```js
var file = {
  files: []
}
console.log(
  Object.keys(file).includes("files"),
  file.files != null,
)
if(file.files){
  console.log(true)
}else{
  console.log(false)
}
```

La siguiente manera de iterar se puede cambiar:

```
for(let i=0;i < file.files.length;i++){
  x = file.files[i];
```

Mejor usar `for in` en este caso:

```
for(let i in file.files){
  x = i;
```

El `getElementsByClassName` se puede cambiar por `querySelector`, agregando un punto al principio `.txt_file_name`:

```
if (x.name) {
  txt.querySelector('.txt_file_name')
    .innerHTML = '<strong>Name:</strong> '+x.name;
};
```

En la siguiente línea veo que se está pasando un parámetro que no está siendo recibido por la función.

```
uploadComplete(p1, function(){snd_upload();console.log('se manda snd_upload')});
```

Es decir, no está recibiendo la función de retrollamada:

```
function(){snd_upload();console.log('se manda snd_upload')}
```

En su lugar, solo está recibiendo `x`:

```
function uploadComplete(x) {
```

Entonces, es mejor que reciba algún parámetro más, podría llamarse `retrol`, para que tenga nombre corto:

```
function uploadComplete(x,retrol) {
```

Para la barra de progreso recomiendo pedir una petición *AJAX* cada 100 milisegundos, o algo parecido, es un pedido que recibirá el número del porcentaje, estaría bien que use *JSON* para este caso.

- https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php

Un ejemplo:

```
$arr = array(
  'porcentaje' => "%10.5",
  'cantidad_de_archivos' => "10",
);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Entonces desde *JavaScript*, se decodificaría así:

```
fetch("/progreso.json").then(function(x){
  return x.text()
}).then(function(respuesta){
  return JSON.parse(respuesta)
})
```